# as3 accessing objects and vars on main timeline from class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, scope, document-class

**I am trying to access vars, functions and objects hard coded on the main timeline from a class.** The Objects, vars etc... are loaded when I call a function in the class like this:

Some code from main timeline:

```
import com.beauMoves;
var bm = new beauMoves();

bm.thisWorks();
```

and below is the class. But it is not accessing the main timeline. In this case I am trying to access a display object loaded from the lib and place on the timeline. The object is called "Beau" as you can see in the code below.

```
   package com {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.*;   

public class beauMoves extends MovieClip 
{


        public function beauMoves()
        {
            // constructor code
            trace("BeauMoves");
        }

        public function thisWorks()
        {
            trace("Cool Beans! This one worked");
                    // THESE TWO LINES BELOW ARE NOT WORKING
            var main:MovieClip = MovieClip(this.parent);
            main.Beau.alpha = .3;

        }

}


}
```

Comment: What frame is this MovieClip on ? Are you sure that when this code runs it's actually on a frame where this MovieClip exists ? You might need to extend your keyframe.

Comment: Everything is on frame one, but using 4 layers. Pretty sure the vars and object are loaded.

Comment: How many frames are there total ? does the keyframe that has this movieclip extend across all the frames ?

Comment: Just one frame and several layers.

Comment: you have just one frame in your fla ? And that instance is named ?

Comment: where do you add bm  to stage before the thisWorks called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming the two lines below are on the main timeline, pass to beauMoves() **this** as a constructor argument:

```
import com.beauMoves;
var bm = new beauMoves( this );
```

Then in your beauMoves() class:

```
package com {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import com.*;   

    public class beauMoves extends MovieClip 
    {
        private var _mainTimeline:MovieClip;

        public function beauMoves( mainTimeLine:MovieClip )
        {
            // constructor code
            trace("BeauMoves");

            _mainTimeline = mainTimeLine;
        }

        public function thisWorks()
        {
            trace("Cool Beans! This one worked");

            _mainTimeline.bm.alpha = .3;

        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you. However, I get this error:beauMoves.as, Line 22 1120: Access of undefined property mainTimeline.

Comment: if line 22 was this: _mainTimeline.bm.alpha = .3;, make sure it has the underscore in front of it.  should be _mainTimeline not mainTimeline.

Comment: yeah, I changed that. I copied and pasted your code and changed it up and then back again but no go. :(

Comment: You were right my friend but it was missing a case sensitive letter. I edited the code and gave you the correct answer. Thank you so much.